# Непонятный вывод программы python в терминале Windows

Tags: python, консоль, windows-11

Я написал обычную программу на python. Вывод чисел от 0 до 50. Но работа программы в терминале Windows (Windows Terminal) была мне абсолютно непонятна.

Хотя в настройках есть "Командная строка" в качестве терминального приложения по умолчанию, при запуске .py из файлового менеджера (дважды щелкните по нему) программа открывается в терминале Windows, но не в "Командной строке", я не понимаю, что с этим делать.

При запуске программы через исполняемый файл .py я столкнулся с таким поведением:

На экране терминала отображались только числа от 21 до 41 и потом снова с 21 до 29, которые помещались в окно терминала, и 21 пустая строка перед ними.

А при изменении размера окна терминала со мной происходили еще более непонятные вещи.

Но когда я запускаю файл непосредственно из Командной Строки в терминале(Command Prompt), то все в порядке.

Операционная система - Windows 11. File .py запускается в Windows Terminal по умолчанию. Код на Python:

```
for i in range(50):
    print(i)
```

Результат выполнения кода:

[image: first half of terminal]

[image: second half of terminal]

Терминал при изменении размера:

[image: terminal with modified sizes]

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться в работе терминала Windows при открытии файла .py. И как это можно исправить, что с этим делать. Я заранее благодарен.

Приложение Терминала по умолчанию - “Командная строка”:

[image: command prompt]

Но запускается не эта программа, а просто терминал Windows.

НО! Если я помещу input() в начало программы, то все будет работать нормально:

```
input()
for i in range(50):
    print(i)
```

[image: normal execution]

Можно ли как-то решить это без input()? И что именно происходит с input() вначале, что он меняет?

Вот ещё примеры выводов первой программы без input(). Слева - неработающая программа, запущенная через исполняемый файл, справа - программа, запущенная через командную строку:

[image: path]

[image: programs]

Comment: Откатитесь до Windows 7 с Python 2.6.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что при выводе текста в консоль на Windows, символы ESC и CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) не интерпретируются корректно, что может привести к непредсказуемым результатам.

Одним из возможных решений проблемы является использование следующего кода на языке Python в начале файла:

```
import os

os.system('cls')
os.system('color 07')
os.system('cls')
```

Данный код позволяет очистить экран консоли и сбросить цветовую схему, что предотвращает непредсказуемое поведение при выводе текста.

Я нашел это решение с помощью ChatGPT - большой языковой модели, разработанной OpenAI. К сожалению, сообщество StackOverflow мне не смогло никак помочь. В какой-то момент оно ещё и было очень недружелюбным. ИИ превосходит во всём. Надеюсь, это поможет вам решить проблему! Если у вас есть дополнительные вопросы, не стесняйтесь задавать их в комментариях.

Не забудьте указать источник, с которого вы получили это решение (ChatGPT). Желаю удачи в вашей работе!

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0

Comment: @Зонтик Я заметил, что рейтинг моего ответа стал "-1". Если его понизили Вы, прошу вас, пожалуйста, пересмотреть Ваше решение, или хотя бы дать мне подробный комментарий, с Вашим мнением и объяснениями. Если это сделали не Вы, то прошу прощения за беспокойство. Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: @Зонтик Ещё прошу всё же учесть, что это мой вопрос, и я сам на него дал ответ, посчитав его уместным.

Comment: я не минусовал ответ.

Comment: @Зонтик Тогда, ещё раз приношу Вам извинения